# Headed down the wrong path (Proof by Induction)

Tags: proof-verification, induction

I'm trying to solve a relatively simply problem, but I believe my path is going the wrong direction, or maybe i'm close and just stuck. Any guidance?

Prove $(1+ \frac{1}{2})^k+ \ge 1+ \frac {k}{2}$

P(1) is true.

Assume P(k) is true, prove P(k+1)

$(1+ \frac{1}{2})^{k+1}  \ge 1+ \frac {k+1}{2}$

$(1+ \frac{1}{2})^1 + (1 + \frac{1}{2})^k \ge 1 + \frac {1}{2} + \frac{k}{2}$

$\frac{3}{2} + 1^k + (\frac{1}{2})^k \ge \frac{3}{2} + \frac {k}{2}$

$\frac{5}{2} + (\frac{1}{2})^k \ge \frac{3}{2} + \frac {k}{2}$

So this is clearly not correct, and I think my problem is in my very first step, but I just don't know what it is.

Comment: I should note that the exponent should be k+1 but my mathJax is bad and I can't figure out how to do that!

Comment: I would try taking your inequality and multiplying each side by $(1 + \tfrac{1}{2})$.

Comment: Use $\{$ and $\}$ rather than $($ and $)$ for your exponent.

Comment: $(1 + \frac{1}{2})^{k+1} \neq (1 + \frac{1}{2})^{1} + (1 + \frac{1}{2})^{k}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start here:

\begin{align}
\left( 1+\frac12\right)^{k+1}&=\left( 1+\frac12\right)^{k}\left( 1+\frac12\right)^{1}
\end{align}

For the next move, you want to use the induction hypothesis.

$$ \left( 1+\frac12\right)^{k} \geq 1+\frac{k}2$$

Comment: AH! Got it :) Because the (1+1/2 ^ k) >= 1+k/2, I can prove that 3/2 >= 1/2. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just multiply both sides by $(1+ \frac{1}{2})$ in induction hypothesis inequation:

$$\begin{align}
\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right)^k  &\ge \left(1+\frac{k}{2}\right) \\
\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right)^k \left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right) &\ge \left(1+\frac{k}{2}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right) \\
 \left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k+1}& \ge 1+\frac{1}{2} + \frac{k}{2} + \frac{k}{4} \\
 &\ge 1 + \frac{k+1}{2}
\end{align}$$

So $P(k) \implies P(k+1)$

Comment: I'm confused as to how this uses k+1 on the RHS. Shouldn't I somewhere see 1+(k+1)/2 , which (I don't believe) is not equivalent to (1+k/2)(1+1/2)

Comment: Or is that not needed.

Comment: @Jeffrey $k/4$ is just a positive term. You have $ 1+\frac{1}{2} + \frac{k}{2} + \frac{k}{4} = 1+ \frac{k+1}{2} + \frac{k}{4}$. This is greater than $1+ \frac{k+1}{2}$.